# Control app execution in Android

Tags: java, android, scheduling

I have two Android apps : 'A' and 'B'.

When 'B' tries to execute a method 'x','A' must do some pretest, then it decides if 'B' can execute this method or not.

I need a solution that keeps the 'B' app unchanged (without including a method call to 'A').

Example: if 'B' tries to execute a heavy-computational method it needs authorization from 'A' to execute it locally or remotely.

Comment: If the two apps are under your control, you could use broadcasts. A sends broadcast that it wants to do something. And B recieves it, decides then broadcasts back whether it is acceptable or not. With A recieving the broadcast response. I realise you dont want to change B. in which case it is impossible. You cant just hack into another App.

Comment: what about a minimum change in B like Visitor pattern ? @Doomsknight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not possible. Nor should it be possible.

If this were possible, since you don't want to change "B", then any app could prevent any other app from executing part of their code, whenever they wanted to. That would be a complete breach of the Android security/privileges system.

What you can do is let "B" decide for itself if it should execute this function. And, if it turns out to be very labor-intensive, let "B" run this operation in the background as a Service.

If you are willing to make small changes in "B", it becomes possible. Let "B"  send an Intent to "A" asking it to do the pre-test. Then depending on the result it gets from "A", it decides if it will execute the function.

Comment: what about a minimum change in B like Visitor pattern ?

Comment: @AbderahmaneMansouri Visitor is usually used within a single program. But with a minimal change to B you can make the thing. Use an Intent that's directed at A, then depending on the result of the Intent, B could decide if it should execute the method.